# How can I read all files from directory c#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, file, streamreader

This is what I want to do:

1. Select a directory
2. Input a string
3. Read all files from that directory in a string.

The idea that I wanna implement is this:

Select the directory, and input a string. Go to each file from that folder. For example the folder is: `Directory={file1.txt,file2.txt,file3.txt}`

I wanna go to file1.txt first, read all the text, into a string, and see if my string is in that file. If yes: do else go to file2.txt, and so on.

Answer (score 17):

```
foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles("directoryName", "searchPattern")
{
    string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
    // Do something with the file content
}
```

You can use `File.ReadAllBytes()` or `File.ReadAllText()` instead of `File.ReadAllLines()` as well, it just depends on your requirements.

Comment: I get this error ... Error 1 The name 'File' does not exist in the current context should I add something ?

Comment: Yea, add 'using System.IO;' next to the other using statements on top of the file

Answer (score 4):

```
        var searchTerm = "SEARCH_TERM";
        var searchDirectory = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"c:\Test\");

        var queryMatchingFiles =
                from file in searchDirectory.GetFiles()
                where file.Extension == ".txt"
                let fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file.FullName)
                where fileContent.Contains(searchTerm)
                select file.FullName;

        foreach (var fileName in queryMatchingFiles)
        {
            // Do something
            Console.WriteLine(fileName);
        }
```

This is a solution based on LINQ, which should also solve your problem. It might be easier to understand and easier to maintain. So if you are able to use LINQ give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

```
            // Only get files that are text files only as you want only .txt 
            string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles("target_directory", "*.txt");
            string fileContent = string.Empty;
            foreach (string file in dirs) 
            {
               // Open the file to read from. 
                fileContent = File.ReadAllText(file);                
                // alternative: Use StreamReader to consume the entire text file.
                //StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file);
                //string fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();

                if(fileContent.Contains("searching_word")){
                  //do whatever you want
                  //exit from foreach loop as you find your match, so no need to iterate
                    break;
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want...

```
string input = "blah blah";
string file_content;
FolderBrowserDialog fld = new FolderBrowserDialog();
if (fld.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(fld.SelectedPath);
    foreach(string f  in Directory.GetFiles(fld.SelectedPath))
    {
        file_content = File.ReadAllText(f);
        if (file_content.Contains(input))
        {
            //string found
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi the easiest way to achieve what you're asking for would be something like this:

```
string[] Files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("Directory_To_Look_In");

foreach (string sFile in Files)
{
    string fileCont = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(sFile);
    if (fileCont.Contains("WordToLookFor") == true)
    {
        //it found something
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks, I get this error ... Error 1 The name 'File' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Nice, I also edited the code slightly and did a test compile. :)